# Indexing text file data

Tags: indexing, tcl

I currently have a text file with 300 rows and 3 columns.

I need to loop over all the rows, assigning 3 variables with the values in the 3 columns.

Here is my pseudo code:

```
for i=1:300
variable1 = element in ith row, 1st column (i,1)
variable2 = element in ith row, 2st column (i,2)
variable3 = element in ith row, 1st column (i,3)
end
```

How do I call the (i,1), (i,2), (i,3) elements in the text file?

Thank you.

Comment: what is the separator? whitespace?

Comment: yup! the separator is whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Text files of that size are easy: they fit in memory trivially. The main problem you're likely to have is that Tcl (in common with *many* programming languages) indexes into things starting at zero, not one.

```
# Read the text in
set f [open "thefile.txt"]
set data [read $f]
close $f

# Split the data into a list of lines
set data [split $data "\n"]

# Now go over the lines and extract the fields
for {set i 0} {$i < 300} {incr i} {
    set line [lindex $data $i]
    set fields [split $line]; # NB: ASSUMES FIELDS SEPARATED BY SINGLE SPACES
    set variable1 [lindex $fields 0]
    set variable2 [lindex $fields 1]
    set variable3 [lindex $fields 2]
}
```

But there's better ways of doing this. In particular, since we're doing all lines in sequence and are always extracting a continuous range of fields, we can be more succinct:

```
set f [open "thefile.txt"]
set data [read $f]
close $f

foreach line [split $data "\n"] {
    lassign [split $line] variable1 variable2 variable3
}
```

The final complexity is that fields aren't necessarily split by single spaces; when there's (even just sometimes) multiple spaces between fields, it fails spectacularly because `split` is actually a pretty stupid command. We fix this by writing some code to do the splitting for us using one of the more powerful Tcl commands; in this case, `regexp` (the regular expression matching command) is the right tool:

```
set f [open "thefile.txt"]
set data [read $f]
close $f

foreach line [split $data "\n"] {
    lassign [regexp -all -inline {\S+} $line] variable1 variable2 variable3
}
```

It's a little bit longer this way, but *far* more robust with real-world data. (The Tcllib textutil package has other approaches for doing this splitting, but the right approach actually depends on what your input data really is. You know this better than we do!)

---

Also, don't forget to actually do something with those variables you've assigned to. Just assigning them is a pretty empty exercise.

Comment: Note that `read` slurps the whole file, including the newline on the last line. When you then `split $data "\n"`, the resulting list will have a trailing empty element due to the empty string following the last newline. I usually use `read -nonewline $f` to mitigate this.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!
I have one more question:

Each time it loops through the for loop, I need to produce one output file with the index number in the output file's name. (That is, in total, I need to produce 300 output files)

For example, for the 49th iteration, I need to produce an output file with the name product-49.out. Do you have any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Just keep a counter variable that you increment: `set n 0; foreach line ... { lassign ...; incr n; puts "$n $var1 $var2 $var3"}`